# Effect on gene loss because of compartmentalisation of plastids/mitochondria/endosymbiont?

Tags: molecular-evolution, symbiosis

Considering the transfer of genes during endosymbiosis a gene transfer event (at least fundamentally, even if it's a special case), how does the fact that in this case the genes are inside a compartment, affect their gene loss, or incorporation into the host/recipient's genome (in context of gene transfer)?

I would imagine that the loss would be slower, recombination with other transferred genes less probable. But I can't find literature on the same. Any leads?

Comment: Could you clarify? What systems are you thinking of? Slower compared with what?

Comment: Slower compared to gene loss if the genes are in the nucleus.

Comment: Still don’t follow. Can you give some examples of the two?

Comment: I don't know if it's true or not. I am assuming that because of compartmentalisation there should be a significant difference in the rate of loss between the two compartments. But I may be very naive and maybe it's trivial that it's not true. What I am asking is for evidence or scientific literature on this topic (because i couldn't find much).

Comment: [Here](https://doi.org/10.1038/348337a0) is an extreme example of **rapid** total loss of photosynthetic genes from a now parasitic organism. Compare that to the rate of loss (or lack of it) for photosynthetic genes in common photosynthetic plants. Now what I am thinking about is a comparison of this rate of loss in plastid genes, to that of genes incorporated into the nucleus. Think about a situation if those photosynthetic genes were incorporated into the nucleus somehow, directly, instead of being in a endosymbiotic compartment (giving rise to a plastid).

Comment: OK. I'm not helping. Perhaps it would be better for someone familiar with this sort of paratism to comment. My own observation is that gene loss is just loss. Gene transfer from organelle to nucleus would seem more complex, but the extent to which it has ocurred in different eukaryotes differs widely.

Comment: The parasite example was just to give an idea of how varied the rate of gene loss can be in general and to provide some context. But I need information on a more general perspective on gene loss. I'll even find it helpful if it's about pressures of natural selection acting differently (or not) on genes in nucleus vs other organelles, which would be something related to gene loss. 

Thanks for the comments anyways.